# ASP.NET MVC 3 Booking System with EF Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello I have a question about a booking scheme. I want a Member to be able to Rent one-or-more Movies. My question is how should I structure it so you can't rent the same movie when it's out on loan. Should I have a variable named Avaliable as a bolean value in the Renting class or something else? thx

```
public class Member
{
    public virtual int MemberId { get; set; }
    public virtual int Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Rental> Rentals { get; set; }
}
 public class Movie
{
    public virtual int MovieId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
 public class Renting
{
    public virtual int RentalId { get; set; }
    public virtual int MovieId { get; set; }
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public virtual int MemberId { get; set; }
    public virtual Member Member { get; set; }

    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime dueDate { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can solve the problem in different ways:

Solution #1 - Or you add a flag on the class Movie > public virtual Bool IsOnStock{get;set;} and when u want to show the available movies to let other member to book it, you just need to select the movies.where(x=> x.IsOnStock)  Simple solution, but keep in mind to UPDATE this field anytime the "status" of renting change.... otherwise it will not work. But I think it's a good idea, because when someone rents a movie and says that will return it in 2 days, maybe that will not happen and you only change that flag when that really happens.

Solution #2- Instead of having a new "property" now you can start "filtering" by accessing the renting entries, taking in consideration the "DateTime.Now" and the date fields in that renting entry. Do something like this: select all movies where ID is NOT in the list of movies where there is an entry where "DateTime.Now" is between the renting dates.

There are more solutions in case if you have multiple copies of the same movie, etc.. but to keep it simple, just use one of the solutions above.